# Sharepoint add in convert from provider hosted to sharepoint hosted

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, add-in

I've developed Sharepoint **add in** (**provider** hosted) using **MVC**. Unfortunately, I need convert it to **sharepoint hosted add in**. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create a SharePoint Hosted App/Add-in but there are some steps you need to take. You will only be using JavaScript so any server communication can be done only through web services or if you want to communicate with SharePoint you can use JSOM.

In order to see how you can create a SharePoint Hosted app please check the next link [Create SharePoint Hosted App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-started-creating-sharepoint-hosted-sharepoint-add-ins).

For more details about this you can check [this link](http://pratapreddypilaka.blogspot.ro/2012/12/apps-in-sharepoint-2013.html) and [this link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/515677/MyplusFirstplusSharepoint-HostedplusAppplusinplus).